# Griffiths and Multipole Expansion, what is each variable in the equation?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, dipole, multipole-expansion

Griffiths defines the formula for the multipole expansion as

$$V(\mathbf r)=\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{r^{(n+1)}}\int(r')^nP_n(\cos\alpha)\rho(\mathbf r')\,d\tau'.$$

But I am confused as to what each variable in this equation represents. It says that they are defined in Figure 3.28, but I am having trouble interpreting this. What are $r$, $r'$, script r, $\tau$, and $\alpha$?

[image]

Comment: Griffiths defines these variables much earlier in his text, have you gone back and reviewed them?

Answer (score 1):

Fix an arbitrary point $\mathcal O$ in 3D as the origin of the rectilinear coordinates system. This $\mathcal O$ (not denoted explicitly in your figure) is the common feet of vectors $\mathbf{r}$ and $\mathbf{r'}$ whose angle between them is $\alpha$. The observation point where you wish to find the potential $V$ is located at $\mathbf{r} = (x,y,z)$. The source of the potential is a distribution of static charges of density $\rho(\mathbf{r'})$ located at $\mathbf{r'} = (x',y'z')$ and distributed in an infinitesimal volume $d \mathbf {\tau}' = dx'dy'dz'$, so  the elementary charge amount in that volume is $\rho(\mathbf{r'})d \mathbf {\tau}'$; the total potential is a summation of the contribution of these charges.

Answer (score 0):

> What are r, r′, script r, τ, and α?

- r is the length of the vector **r**.
- r′ is the the length of the vector **r′**.
- script r is the length of the vector **r - r′**.
- τ (or τ′) signify volume. The symbol dτ′ in the figure represents an infinitesimal volume element at the location of **r′**.
- α is the angle between **r** and **r′**